# Laravel 4 optional paramaters in named routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes, optional-parameters

I have this route with an optional parameters:

```
Route::get('{id}/results/subject/{subject_id}/{step_id?}', array('as' =>'test', 'uses' => '\Controllers\TestController@Show'));
```

and I got this in my TestController

```
function Show($id, $subject_id, $step_id){
//Some stuff
}
```

I want to attribute a default value to my optional `step_id` parameter just like [here](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters). If I don't attribute a default value, I got a missing parameter error for my controller.

I've tried

```
Route::get('{id}/results/subject/{subject_id}/{step_id?}', array('as' =>'test', 'uses' => '\Controllers\TestController@Show', function($step_id = '3'){return $step_id});
```

and

```
Route::get('{id}/results/subject/{subject_id}/{step_id?}',function($step_id = '3'){return $step_id}, array('as' =>'test', 'uses' => '\Controllers\TestController@Show'));
```

but both are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the default in your function like so.

```
function ShowFactorRat($id, $subject_id, $step_id="default value here"){
//Some stuff
}
```